# Is any protection for display needed against scratches from keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro

If the MacBook is closed can it happen that the keyboard touch and scratch display?

I don't mean anything to be put on the screen but something between display and key.

If you got a new MacBook there is some thin paper that cover your keyboard. I think it is there to "defend" display while transportation. Thats why is the question - do we need something like this if the notebook is transported for example in a bag?

Comment: You definitely don't need this: so long as there's no dust or anything raised off of the keys, your screen is totally safe (I've owned an rMBP for 2 years and never had anything between keys and screen even during rough travel; no damage at all to my screen, even if I look really closely).

Comment: @owlswipe thx for the answer. Why does apple give than this paper between screen and keys? If its not needed at all. The transportation from apple store to someones home its near the same as your travels even with much less times.

Comment: They do that less for you transporting it and more for UPS handlers carelessly throwing it onto a 747. And, I've got a full answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On old Powerbooks (the G4 specifically) the keyboard would sometimes leave an annoying permanent imprint on the screen. However, with any new Macbook, this is not an issue: the keys are now softer and further away from the screen, so they should never touch.

In my experience, trekking around with my rMBP, no protection is needed: I've traveled pretty roughly with the computer with no protection on and the screen is in perfect condition (even if I look closely). Just make sure no dust or other particles are on top of your keys because the added height may cause it to touch the screen.

As far as why Apple ships MBs with foam screen protectors, it is apparently to protect they screen during the roughness of shipping (where there is significantly more bounce for the keyboard and screen to deal with than you'll subject it to in your use of it); I think any damage is rare enough that you don't need to protect the screen, though Apple does want to ensure that every MB is opened upon delivery in perfect condition (thus the foam insert).

**tl:dr**: Don't worry about it! You're much more likely to damage it by spilling liquid onto it, dropping it, or leaving it around pets.

For more, here's a [forum discussion about your question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/983317?tstart=0).

Comment: Thanks for explanation, i was disappointed using a screen protector / microfiber between keyboard and screen on a such expensive laptop.